# Changing From Assert Function in C To If Statement

Tags: c, tree, assert, red-black-tree

I have found some code online for red black trees, and am trying to implement it.

I do not want to use the `assert` function though which the original code has located [here](http://en.literateprograms.org/Red-black_tree_%28C%29)

I am getting a seg fault on the line `n->color = child->color;` just before the delete fix. After debugging I discovered that the child did not exist in this case, and so the reason for the assert statement in the original code. I decided to add what I thought was appropriate with the additional if clause around everything from where child is dealt with downward.

However, now the program does not actually delete, because if the child does not exist, it never makes it into the loop. After trial and error I still cannot find where to close the if clause in order to take the place of the assert statement properly.

Please let me know your ideas!

Here is my "translated" code without the assert, and using an if statement instead.

```
void delete_node(int key)
{
    node* child;
    node* n ;

   n = searchTree(key);

    if(n == NULL)return;

    if(n->left != NULL && n->right != NULL)
    {
        node* pred = n->left;
        while(pred->right != NULL)
            pred = pred->right;

        n->value = pred->value;
        n = pred;
    }
if(n->right != NULL || n->left != NULL){

    child = n->right == NULL ? n->left : n->right;
    if(n->color == 'b')
    {
        n->color = child->color;
        delete_fix1(n);
    }

    swap_nodes(n, child);
    if(n->parent == NULL && child != NULL)
        child->color = 'b';
    free(n);

}

}
```

Test data (Seg Fault occurs when attempting to delete 4):
i stand for insert (insert occurs flawlessly as far as I can tell)
d stands for delete

```
i 7
i 8
i 1
d 8
i 4
i 10
d 4
i 11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
assert(n->left == NULL || n->right == NULL)
```

Is nowhere *near* this:

```
if (n->right != NULL || n->left != NULL)
```

Recheck your translation. The assert states that one of them *must* be NULL. your if-expr evals true if *either* are **not** NULL. Your if-expr passes if both are non-null, where the assert would fail. Likewise, your if-expr fails if both are NULL, while the assert would pass.

Don't take shortcuts when doing this kinda of thing. First. **keep the asserts regardless of your added checks**. Second, until it is up and working, copy the assert clauses verbatim in your if (expr): or (!(expr)) for bailout conditions.

**verbatim check:**

```
assert(n->left == NULL || n->right == NULL)
if (n->left == NULL || n->right == NULL)...
```

**bailout check:**

```
assert(n->left == NULL || n->right == NULL)
if (!(n->left == NULL || n->right == NULL))
    bailout loud.
```

**EDIT** Translation of linked code with integrated if-expr

```
void rbtree_delete(rbtree t, void* key, compare_func compare)
{
    node child;
    node n = lookup_node(t, key, compare);
    if (n == NULL) return;  /* Key not found, do nothing */
    if (n->left != NULL && n->right != NULL) {
        /* Copy key/value from predecessor and then delete it instead */
        node pred = maximum_node(n->left);
        n->key   = pred->key;
        n->value = pred->value;
        n = pred;
    }

    assert(n->left == NULL || n->right == NULL);
    if (n->left == NULL || n->right == NULL) // << note: SAME as above
    {
        child = n->right == NULL ? n->left  : n->right;
        if (node_color(n) == BLACK) {
            n->color = node_color(child);
            delete_case1(t, n);
        }
        replace_node(t, n, child);
        if (n->parent == NULL && child != NULL)
            child->color = BLACK;
        free(n);
    }

    verify_properties(t);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see your point. Perhaps I'm missing the true error then, or the ending of my if statement is still in the incorrect place (at the end of the function basically). I'm still having the issue that nothing is actually deleted from the tree when I run it though. Any thoughts? It must be that the code is never entering the if clause now

Comment: And again if I'm understanding how the assert statement works, then if that condition isn't met it should exit anyway which is why I justified placing everything under it in the if clause.

Comment: @ZAX correct . `assert(expr)` means "this better be true or I'm going to throw a big error in debug-mode and give the middle-finger to the operator".

Comment: @ZAX and its not your if-statement placement. its the expression leading into it. Your if-expr is **failing** (and thus the block being skipped) on data that should *not* be. **Replicate the assertion expression for your if-expr.**

Comment: I have recently just decided to use the assert.h so that I can try the original assert statement instead, and even that gives me the same seg fault. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ZAX is your if-expr check there as well? and more importantly, does it match the expression in the `assert(expr)` *exactly* ? The code above does not. **it must**. See updated answer for direct-xlat of linked code.

Comment: I removed the if statement for the time being, and just have the assert, just as is the original code. I believe the issue is occuring when n has no children (both left and right are null). When I assign the child->color an error occurs since no color exists. Thoughts on the matter? Perhaps the issue is not so much with the assertion, but rather with finding the predecessor since the code appears to want the predecessor to have one child?

Comment: I've uploaded a test set of data so that you can see where the issue is occuring. Please try and take a look at it. I'd really apprciate it

Comment: @ZAX sry. took a nap there. as before, not *exactly* the same as the original algorithm. Your code dereferences `child` to obtain color, the original code uses a static function, `node_color(node n)` that returns BLACK on `(n==NULL)`, otherwise return n->color.